# How to display the data when name, email, username or D.O.B is entered in the input text?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Welcome.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        include_once 'connect.php';
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from `users` where userid='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        echo 'Welcome - ' . $row['username'];
        ?>

        <br>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        <br><br>

        <?php
        include_once 'connect.php';
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users");

        echo "<table border='1'>
                        <tr>
                        <th>User_ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Date_of_birth</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Date_of_birth'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><img alt='image' style='width:100px;height:50px;' src='upload/" . $row['filename'] . "'></td>";
            echo "<td> <a href='editform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
            echo "<td> <a href='deleteform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        include_once 'connect.php';
        if (isset($_POST["happy"])) {

            if (empty($_POST["happy"])) { //not empty name
                echo '<br>';
                echo "No letter entered";
            } else {

                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userid='$id'";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $sql = "select name, username, email, Date_of_birth from `users` where (name LIKE '%$name%' OR username LIKE '%$name%' OR email LIKE '%$name%' OR Date_of_birth LIKE '%$name%')";
                if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    print_r($id);
                } else {
                    echo 'No record found';
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <br>
            Search: <input type="text" name="happy"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Problem:

I have a welcome page with all the users data who have registered. In my welcome page their is an input field, so when I enter anyone's name,username,email,D.O.B say pavan or pavan1994@gamil.com , then all the row matches with this entered data, only those row should be displayed.

Comment: What is issue or error please put here

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 82

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 82

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 82

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 82

Comment: above errors i'm getting sir

Comment: First thing don't include include_once 'connect.php'; many times.

Comment: im not getting it how to do please help me sir

Comment: please help me sir how to do please

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code please try it.

```
<?php
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            header('location:login.php');
        }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    include_once 'connect.php';
     $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from `users` where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    echo 'Welcome - '.$row['username'];
    ?>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    <?php
     //include_once 'connect.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users");
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
       <th>User_ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>E-mail</th>
       <th>Department</th>
       <th>Date_of_birth</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Image</th>
       <th>Action</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>";
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['Date_of_birth'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td><img alt='image' style='width:100px;height:50px;' src='upload/".$row['filename']."'></td>";
     echo "<td> <a href='editform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Edit</a></td>";
     echo "<td> <a href='deleteform.php?id=" . $row['userid'] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
       }
      echo "</table>";
    ?>
      <?php

       //include_once 'connect.php';   
        if(isset($_POST["happy"])){
       if(empty($_POST["happy"])){ //not empty name
          echo '<br>';
              echo "No letter entered";
        }else {
            $name = $_POST["happy"];
             $id = $_GET['id'];
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userid='$id'";
              $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
              $sql="select name, username, email, Date_of_birth from `users` where (name LIKE '%$name%' OR username LIKE '%$name%' OR email LIKE '%$name%' OR Date_of_birth LIKE '%$name%')";
           if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) === TRUE) {
                            print_r($id);
      }else {
     echo 'No record found';
       }

     }

     }

     ?>

            <form method="post">
                <br>
                Search: <input type="text" name="happy"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>                 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 3

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 61

Comment: please help me sir how to do please

Comment: Please try it now

Comment: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 59

Comment: where did you put `id` in `$_SESSION['id']`?

Comment: sir i guess v should not use this print_r

Comment: Hey @pavankumar, Please print_r($_SESSION) at top of page and see what is coming in session.

Comment: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration_form_2\welcome.php on line 2

Comment: pls guide me sir